# QGIS Composer Legend Filter by Map Content Not Showing Item

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I'm trying to filter a composer using the Filter by Map Content Button. It works for the most part. There is a line layer that doesn't fit completely in the map window that gets filtered out, I'm guessing because the whole layer isn't present. Is there a way to over ride a single layer so it shows up even while using this button to filter the rest?